# Text effects on hover

Tags: text, hover, processing, mouseover

I'm trying to create a simple effect of a mouseover (or hover) in processing. I have been able to do this effect on shapes only, such as rectangles, ellipses etc. but I cannot figure out how to do it on text objects.

For example to detect mouseover on a circle:

```java
if (sqrt(sq(x - mouseX) + sq(y - mouseX)) < diameter/2 ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The effect will be as simple as changing the text color to indicate that the mouse is over the text.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **bounding box** which is just a rectangle that is "drawn" around the text. (That rectangle usually doesn't actually get drawn, except for debugging.)

You can get the bounding box of text using the `textWidth()` function and its friends, which you can read about in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Then when you have that bounding box, you can use the collision detection code for rectangles that you already have.

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting a disconnected snippet.